# Visual C++ 6: Import 24-Bit-Bitmaps as resource

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, resources

I have a problem. I have a project in visual c++ 6 where I have to laod an image and put it onto the window. That was no problem. The bitmap I load is imported into resources (so part of project).

But, the image which I want to load is a 24-bit-bitmap. But as long as I know, in VC++6 I can only import 8-bit-bitmaps, because when I import the 24-bit-image in VC++6, then the colors are changed or an error occurs. Only when I loaded an 8-bit-bitmap, no colors where changed.

So the question: Is it possible to import a 24-bit-bitmap in Visual C++ as a resource

Comment: You are of course aware that VC6 was end - of - life 'ed approximately a million years ago.

Comment: Add the ressource in the RC file with a text editor.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Yes I know, but VC6 was not my choice ;) It is an old project which only should be corrected minimal.

Comment: @manuell: This is a possibility. I'll try this.